# имитация работы select

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.color-picker .block>label').click(function() {
  var th = $(this);
  $('.choise').replaceWith(th.addClass('to-choise'));
  $('.color-picker .block').prepend(th);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-picker"><span>Цвет:</span>
  <form action="">
    <div class="choise">
      <label class="to-choise">
        <div class="box red"></div>
        <div class="name">Красный</div>
      </label>
      <div class="block hidden">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box red"></div>
          <div class="name">Красный</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box orange"></div>
          <div class="name">Оранжевый</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box yellow"></div>
          <div class="name">Желтый</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box green"></div>
          <div class="name">Зеленый</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box lblue"></div>
          <div class="name">Голубой</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box blue"></div>
          <div class="name">Синий</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box violet"></div>
          <div class="name">Фиолетовый</div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

В теории этот код должен заменять `label class="to-choise"` на выбранный `label` из `.block`, но получается все совсем не так, а именно:

1. Пропадает блок `.block`
2. Пропадает блок `.choise`
3. Вставляется `label` сразу после `form`

А как должно происходить:

1. Выбранный `label` из `.block` заменяется на `label` перед `.block`
2. Выбранный `label` из `.block` помещается в начало `.block`

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Заменил `.choise` на `.to-choise` (кажется вы изначально ошиблись с классом)
2. Добавил `clone()` в `replaceWith` (чтобы элемент оставался на месте, а вставляли клонируемый)
3. Для наглядности добавил удаление `input` из клонируемого объекта (чтобы не добавлялась радио-кнопка)
4. Добавил классу `.to-choise` красного цвета (чтобы было видно наглядно)
5. В HTML разметку добавил один `<br>` (чтобы отделить следующий блок)

```js
$('.color-picker .block>label').click(function() {
  var th = $(this);
  var newElemnt = th.clone().addClass('to-choise'); 
  newElemnt.children().remove('input');
  $('.to-choise').replaceWith(newElemnt);
  $('.color-picker .block').prepend(th);
});
```

```css
.to-choise {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-picker"><span>Цвет:</span>
  <form action="">
    <div class="choise">
      <label class="to-choise">
        <div class="box red"></div>
        <div class="name">Красный</div>
      </label>
      <br>
      <div class="block hidden">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box red"></div>
          <div class="name">Красный</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box orange"></div>
          <div class="name">Оранжевый</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box yellow"></div>
          <div class="name">Желтый</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box green"></div>
          <div class="name">Зеленый</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box lblue"></div>
          <div class="name">Голубой</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box blue"></div>
          <div class="name">Синий</div>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="pickColor"/>
          <div class="box violet"></div>
          <div class="name">Фиолетовый</div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Для ознакомления, ссылки на документацию по использованным методам (хотя из названий все должно быть ясно):

- [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)
- [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало)